# JSONP Ajax callback not firing

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm trying to use JSONP to call a webservice, passing in an integer to get two integers out. Normally I'd use regular JSON, but I'm calling to a different port number (to a webservice, from a website, but both in the same domain).

For context, I'm passing in the user id to get out the number of unread tasks and notices, to populate some figures shown on the screen.

Here's the code:

```
var url = "localhost:13742/api/notices/get" ;
$.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", $("#__UserId").val(), function (response) {
    console.log("Number of unread tasks- " + response.UnreadTasks + ". Number of unread notices- " + response.UnreadNotices);
});
```

As the title suggests, the callback I've specified isn't being fired- I'm not getting any logs, including errors. I know the server-side code is working because I can manually get to it through the browser- I just pass in the query string and it works fine (returns the information as an XML document). There's no security on it for now, so I don't have to worry about passing in authentication headers.

This is my first time using JSONP, although I've used regular JSON plenty. Maybe there's a simpler option given that I can do it so easily through the browser.

Comment: Are you sure the server is returning JSONP?  Can you show us what's returned from the URL?  JSONP is *not* JSON.  It's actually a JavaScript file containing a function call.  The function called is what is passed in `callback=`.  You say it returns an XML document?  That's wrong.  That's not JSONP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a client-side issue. Apparently the user id needed to be included in the URL. Seems the server was alright after all. Rather boring solution, but there we go.

Thanks to everyone that assisted.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "localhost:13742/api/Notices/" + $("#__UserId").val(),
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Number of unread tasks- " + data.UnreadTasks + ". Number of unread notices- " + data.UnreadNotices);
            },
            error: function (jxhr, status, err) {
                console.log("Error, status = " + status + ", err = " + err);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server needs to return a valid JSONP response for this to work.  JSONP is special in that it is just a JavaScript file.  That's how it works cross-domain, because it just adds a `<script>` tag to your head.

JSONP is *not* JSON, nor is it XML.  You say your URL returns the data as an XML document?  That's incorrect.  That's why it's not working.

JSONP should just be a function call, to the function passed in via `callback=`, with the data as the 1st parameter.

I don't know what language your server is, but in PHP it could look like this:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'UnreadTasks' => 5,
    'UnreadNotices' => 8
);

header('Content-type: application/javascript');
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($data) . ');';
```

Comment: this is solution to millions. i have strolled many answers on stackoverflow but nobody mentioned the server side. This is the most clear answer. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ajax` like this:

```
$.ajax({

  url: "localhost:13742/api/notices/get",

  dataType: "jsonp",

  data: $("#__UserId").val(),

  success: function(data) {
    console.log("Number of unread tasks- " + data.UnreadTasks + ". Number of unread notices- " + data.UnreadNotices);
  },

  error: function(jxhr, status, err) {
    console.log("Error, status = " + status + ", err = " + err);
  }
});
```

Also did you make sure 'localhost:13742/api/notices/get' supports jsonp - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Get rid of the `jsonpCallback` option.  jQuery will set that for you, and call your `success` function.

Comment: Removed it since I guess its not `required` in this case(and most) but just wanted to point that its not entirely unnecessary. Even jquery official documents states `You may want to specify the callback when you want to enable better browser caching of GET requests.`. But I agree that for most cases it is unnecessary, in fact not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I tried your code and it didn't work, but this may just be because of the server. I haven't done anything to get it work with JSONP (mainly because I don't know how to), so I'll work on that next.

I'll be sure to mark this as the answer if that's the problem.